# map() Mongo db Query - jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb

Please see my database query:

```
db.comments
    .find({})
    .forEach(function(doc) { 
                        doc.comments.map(function(c) {
                                if (c.active == 1) {
                                    c.status = 0;
                                 }
                        }); 
                        db.comments.update(
                                      {_id: doc._id}, 
                                      {$set: {comments: doc.comments}});
     });
```

I need to write with jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. please help me If anyone has an idea to solve this

Comment: Where is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: @TimBourguignon how to write modal query using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {}

$comments = Comment::all();
foreach ($comments as $c) {
    $c->comments = array_map(function (&$com) {
        if ($com->active == 1) $com->status = 0;
    }, $c->comments);
    $c->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I have an issue , If I have find condition how to modify this code ?

Comment: Can you mention your condition? You can do `$comments = Comment::where('votes', '>', 100)->get()` . Follow the examples listed here https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#examples

Comment: Yes but I tried it, but at that moment $c is not an object.